# Neoclassical Growth Model with Technology Investment

Tags: macroeconomics, technology, technological-progress

I am reading Parente & Prescott 1994 JPE. This is just a typical neoclassical model with the extension of a global technology diffusion function and firm investment in technology.

Firms have technology on production $Y_{t}=h_{t} \cdot A_{t} \cdot N_{t} \cdot K_{t}^{\theta_{k}}$  and on investment $X_{A t}=\pi \int_{A_{t}}^{A_{t+1}}\left(\frac{S}{W_{t}}\right)^{\alpha} d S$, where $X_{At}$ is the investment cost of increasing $A_t$ to $A_{t+1}$, and $W_t$ is the world frontier level of technology which grows at exogenous rate $\gamma$.

The authors show that these can be rewritten as  $Y_{t}=\mu \cdot h_{t} \cdot(1+\gamma)^{\left(1-\theta_{z}\right) t} \cdot \bar{N} \cdot K_{t}^{\theta_{k}} \cdot Z_{t}^{\theta_{z}}$ and $Z_{t+1}=\frac{1}{(1+\gamma)^{\left(1-\theta_{z}\right) / \theta_{z}}} \cdot Z_{t}+\frac{1}{\pi} X_{z t}$ where $Z_{t} \equiv \frac{A_{t}^{\alpha+1}}{W_{0}^{\alpha}(1+\gamma)^{\alpha(t-1)}(1+\alpha)}$,  $X_{z t} \equiv X_{A t}$, and $\theta_{z} \equiv 1 /(1+\alpha)$.

Firm maximizes PV of its dividends, $V\left(Z_{0}\right)=\max \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} p_{t} V_{f t}$ where  $V_{f t}=Y_{t}-w_{t}\left(h_{t}\right) \bar{N}-r_{k t} K_{t}-X_{z t}$.

The household side is quite textbook:  $\max \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \beta^{t}\left[\ln \left(c_{t}\right)+\phi_{d} \ln \left(d_{t}\right)+\phi_{l} \ln \left(1-h_{t}\right)\right]$ except that there is another household type physical capital $d_{t}$.

My question here is that while the technology investment $X_{zt}$ seems to be a choice of the dynamic problem of the firm, the authors construct the competitive equilibrium by recognizing $Z_t$ as a static optimization choice. In particular, they have

[image].

I wonder how comes equation (20) and why we can simply ignore the dynamic problem of choosing $X_{zt}$.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question about the equation 20. It gives you definition for r_zt equation 20 is not derived as far as I can see

Comment: @1muflon1 Yes it is a definition in the model (the authors call it  "implicit rental price") but it should be still derived from somewhere like $r_{kt}$ and $r_{dt}$. For example I think the equation of $r_{kt}$ is from $rk-\tau(r-\delta)k - \delta k =k i$.